# Unable to execute jar file in a ubuntu server

Tags: eclipse, hadoop, sqoop, ubuntu-16.04, ubuntu-server

I have a small sqoop import project where i have to import from mysql to hdfs. It is a maven project, while i am running in my local system it works fine. Now when i am trying to run in my ubuntu server by running a jar file, **it is executing but not showing any output. It is not a web based application, normal application where i am running hadoop deamons and running this project.** Tell me how to run this type of projects in servers and run.

```
package org.ezytruk.sqoop;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.util.Properties;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool;

import com.cloudera.sqoop.SqoopOptions;
import com.cloudera.sqoop.SqoopOptions.FileLayout;

public class SqoopImport {
    public static void importMySQLToHDFS() throws Exception {
        try {
            String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
            Class.forName(driver).newInstance();

            Configuration config = new Configuration();
            config.addResource(new Path("/usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop/conf/core-site.xml"));
            config.addResource(new Path("/usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop/conf/hdfs-site.xml"));

            Properties properties = new Properties();
            properties.load(new FileInputStream("/home/*****/SqoopImportHDFS/resources/sqoopImport.properties"));

            //org.apache.sqoop.SqoopOptions sqoopOptions = new org.apache.sqoop.SqoopOptions();
            SqoopOptions sqoopOptions = new SqoopOptions();
            sqoopOptions.setDriverClassName(driver);
            sqoopOptions.setHadoopHome("/usr/local/hadoop");
            sqoopOptions.setConnectString(properties.getProperty("db_mysql_connection_string"));
            sqoopOptions.setTableName(properties.getProperty("db_mysql_table_name"));
            sqoopOptions.setUsername(properties.getProperty("db_mysql_username"));
            sqoopOptions.setPassword(properties.getProperty("db_mysql_password"));
            sqoopOptions.setNumMappers(1);
            //sqoopOptions.setWarehouseDir(properties.getProperty("db_hdfs_warehouse_directory"));
            sqoopOptions.setTargetDir(properties.getProperty("db_hdfs_output_directory"));
            sqoopOptions.setFileLayout(FileLayout.TextFile);
            new ImportTool().run(sqoopOptions);

            } catch (Exception e) {

         }

     }
       public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        SqoopImport mySqlImport = new SqoopImport();
        mySqlImport.importMySQLToHDFS();

    }

}
```

Comment: If this is works but not showing result to console then probably your default output is not the console. May be servers default output changed. What is java version in server?

Comment: java version-1.8